# Problem with bash(system->wget) command in c++

Tags: c++, bash

here is my code:

```
string line;
ifstream toOpen;
toOpen.open("allfiles.txt", ios::in);
int fileCounter=0;

if(toOpen.is_open()){
    while(!toOpen.eof()){
        getline(toOpen,line);
        string dl = "wget -q -E -O  superman/" + href[0] + " " + line;
        //cout << dl << endl;
        fileCounter++;
        system(dl);
    }

    toOpen.close();
}
```

Where the allfiles.txt (the content):

```
http://www.xxx.com/index1.html
http://www.xxx.com/index2.html
```

Where href[] values are like: {index1.html, index2.html, index3.html ...}

My error message:

```
file.cpp:XX: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int system(const char*)’
```

Comment: Have you really never come across `std::string::c_str()`?

Comment: @ignacio: I think i get it now. Sorry for this kind of noob question. I just started c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function 'system' takes a 'const char *' as argument but you gave it an std::string. Try

```
system(dl.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

`system` wants a `const char *` argument, so you have to call `dl.c_str()` to get a `char *` to the `std::string`'s data.

```
    system(dl.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

`system()` know nothing about C++ types. You have to give it `char*` like this:

```
system(dl.c_str());
```